# Extract only specific language subs from a MKV file?

Tags: python

I own a folder with lots of .mkv files, each of which contains 10 subtitle tracks. The subs' are set with the respective language (title is blank, but the language is set "en"; "ja"; "it"; "fr" and so on...)

My goal is to use the terminal to search and extract the italian and english subs only from within the .mkv files.

Is anyone able to produce a working script to simply look into the mkv's and extract the italian and english subs only?

This was my python code draft:

```
import os
import subprocess

# Imposta la directory in cui si trovano i file .mkv
directory = "/Volumes/2TB Lexar NM620/aaa_Lavori_MUX_Terminale"

# Esegui il lavoro sugli MKV
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".mkv"):
        print(f"File {file} in elaborazione...")

        # Esegui mkvinfo per ottenere informazioni sulle tracce
        mkv_info = subprocess.check_output(["mkvinfo", os.path.join(directory, file)]).decode("utf-8")

        # Verifica se ci sono tracce di sottotitoli in italiano (sia .ass che .srt)
        if "Codec ID: S_TEXT/ASS" in mkv_info or "Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8" in mkv_info:
            # Estrai le tracce audio e video
            subprocess.run(["mkvextract", "tracks", os.path.join(directory, file), "0:video.h265"])

            # Estrai i sottotitoli in italiano ed inglese
            subprocess.run(["mkvextract", "tracks", os.path.join(directory, file), f"1:{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}_ita.ass"])
            subprocess.run(["mkvextract", "tracks", os.path.join(directory, file), f"2:{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}_eng.ass"])

            # Rinomina i file
            episode_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, f"{episode_name}_ita.ass")):
                os.rename(os.path.join(directory, f"{episode_name}_ita.ass"), os.path.join(directory, f"{episode_name}_Subtitles01.ITA.ass"))
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, f"{episode_name}_eng.ass")):
                os.rename(os.path.join(directory, f"{episode_name}_eng.ass"), os.path.join(directory, f"{episode_name}_Subtitles02.ENG.ass"))

            print(f"File {file} analizzato e rinominato con successo.")

print("Tutti i file sono stati analizzati, rinominati ed estratti i sottotitoli.")
```